# How to convert a Visual Studio 2010 C++/CLI project to a Visual Studio 2008 project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

Does somebody know how to convert a Visual Studio 2010 C++/CLI project to a Visual Studio 2008 project? I have only found hints and tools regarding C# projects.

Comment: Is this a one-off or do you have hundreds of projects? The simplest way is to make a new project in VS2008 and copy all the source files over, then work through the project properties in both versions and set them up identically - but that doesn't scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no practical way to do this, the project file format for C++ projects has dramatically changed in VS2010.  As a result of a re-engineering effort to make them use MSBuild to build projects, just like the other supported languages.  Even the filename extension has changed, from .vcproj to .vcxproj.

You'll need to re-create the project in VS2008.